# net use in cmd script hangs forever - how to set a timeout if server denies connection

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, timeout, abort

I have a Windows batch file which connects several network drives. It first pings the servers, and if that succeds, it then tries to map the share with `net use ...`:

```
SET host=mini3
IF /I NOT %host% == %COMPUTERNAME% (
    ping -4 -n 2 -w 1000 %host% | find "TTL=" > NUL
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (
        echo Q: == \\%host%\Q_ -- mini3-Volumes
        net use Q: \\%host%\Q_ /persistent:yes > NUL && echo OK
    ) ELSE (
        echo %host% not found. Skipping.
    )
)
```

Sometimes, even though the machine is reachable by ping, the `net use` command hangs forever. The reason it hangs seems due to a misconfiguration in the SMB server, and/or in the Windows Credentials stored on the client.

So when that happens, for whatever reason, I would like to print an error and go on to the next drive to map.

The Windows `Timeout` command seems to actually be a "delay" command, equivalent of Unix `sleep`, and not a timeout.

Is there a good way to have a real timeout for a `net use` command, without aborting the entire .cmd script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few mods I have no problem
key was correcting %errorlevel% as no runtime delay was included/needed
the drive mappings are spawned independently so the tasks can progress
There should be a brief flash if all is well, otherwise if share is not found they should timeout naturally.

Advent is in my case another workstation rather than server. Change that back to `mini3`

[image]

```
@echo off
SET "host=Advent"

IF /I NOT "%host%"=="%COMPUTERNAME%" (
    ping -4 -n 2 -w 1000 %host% | find "TTL=" > NUL
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        echo Q: == \\%host%\Q_ -- %host%-Volumes
        START "Z Drive" net use Z: \\%host%\users /persistent:yes
        START "Q Drive" net use Q: \\%host%\Q_ /persistent:yes
REM surplus from above line > NUL && echo OK
    ) ELSE (
        echo %host% not found. Skipping.
    )
)

rem delay this file so it waits to let the new connections process above
timeout 2
net use | find ":"
```

Comment: Indeed, the problem was the `> NUL` redirection in cases when it had to ask for username/password. Now it would still be useful to find a Windows equivalent of the Unix `timeout` command, but that should probably be a separate question.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of `net use` itself: With `START` a new user context is set up and the script itself proceeds. If the script itself depends on the existing net share it is necessary to use `net use` without `START`.

Comment: I've received one new item in my Stack Exchange inbox (some days later this item disappeared, but this is another topic) concerning my comment from Apr 8 saying that the OP requirement was not to hang on net use. Perhaps my comment was not precise enough: I appreciate the solution. However this solution does not work if the script itself depends on the existence of the drive defined by `NET USE`. E. g. in the solution you could not call to some file located on drive Z: or drive Q: because the `NET USE` is not in the user's context.

Comment: Hint: I've discovered this question (69220610) because I was searching without success in the internet how to deal with "hanging forever" of `NET USE` (idea: Some sort of time-out, preferable with possibility for defining the time-out duration).

Comment: @K J thanks for your input - I don't know if the rules of stackoverflow allows to extend the topic, but we are all curious... My start point of my research is some sort of replacement of autoexec.bat using regedit key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`. With that key it is possible to call a bat-File starting shell by WIN+R, cmd. One of the first checks in my script is checking if a drive exists and if not reconnect. On my environment the net use was hanging for +- 3 minutes and I have to kill the shell.

Comment: @K J (continued): The missing drive was pointing to some big NAS (perhaps EMC?) but sure nothing of windows ecosystem. It could be that indeed the timeout behaviour depends on implementation on the server side (this would be my conclusion of our discussion). In my case the result was dramatically - I'm using different scripts for my work and every script was hanging due the problems to connect to the drive.